Why do i get this error? form-bindings: Class to bind does not exist or is excluded from compilation

I am making a login and registration application in java. I want the users to receive a confirmation email. My registration and login forms are ready, and the springboot mail sender app is also ready. I created the springboot mailsender using the spring initializer, and on the main >> java >> along with my mailsender program, in the same directory, I added the login and registration forms Java folder. Now it seems to throw this error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to SO. You might want to read [ask] and as the bot says post relevant code of what you're trying to do. Also put yourself into our position when updating your question, i.e. try to think about what helps us help you, e.g. what information, how should it be presented (formatting) etc.

Try to clean and rebuild or check dependencies and imports.
